# How to get exact timezone to show "you answerd days/hour ago"?

Tags: php, mysql

I am from South Korea, My Time Zone is GMT+9

If any comment was posted 22-10-2014( I don't know how get daytime(am/pm))

```
<?php

$date = date_parse_from_format('d-m-Y', '22-10-2014');

$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year']);

$current_time   = time();

$time=$current_time-$timestamp;

echo "<br/>diff ".$time;

?>
```

From Above I might get how much seconds/minutes/hours based on $time. But How to leave timezone on the server(anywhere in the world)? How to put exact time of post on that day, so that I can say , this post was posted exactly (s/m/h/d/week/month/year) ago.

Here is I tried with mysql...

```
   <?php
   $current_time=time();
   //echo time(); 

   $postdate=date("d-m-Y ");
   $date = date_parse_from_format('d-m-Y', $postdate);
   //echo"<br/> date". $postdate;
   $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year']);
   //echo"<br/> timestamp". $timestamp;

    $insert =mysql_query("UPDATE time SET time = '$timestamp' WHERE username='madhusudan'");

    $call=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM time WHERE username='madhusudan'");
       while($num=mysql_fetch_assoc($call)){
       $time_db=$num['time'];

       }
    $time=$current_time-$time_db;
    echo $time;

    ?>


input date=23-10-2014
data inserted in database=1414015200


Result
$time=54769 


But, I inserted just few second ago??????

How to solve it Bro.....
```

Comment: use gmt to store and compare. only change timezone when you need to display.

Comment: @exussum, Can you please explain with an easy example, actually I am really new to code.